# python UnicodeDecodeError on long query using pyorient

Tags: python, orientdb, pyorient

I'm using OrientDB and pyorient to query it using python 
my issue raised when trying to make a long query like :

```
select * from (traverse in('written_on') from (select * from (traverse in('posted_by') from (select * from person where @rid=#14:0) ) ) where @class='Comment'
```

an UcodingDecodingError happens
here is my code :

```
$ python 
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyorient 
>>> client = pyorient.OrientDB('localhost',2424)
>>> client.connect('root','root')
10
>>> db = client.db_open('DummyData','root','root')
>>> persons=client.query('select * from person')
>>> for person in persons:
...     print person.name
... 
[GOOD RESULT]
>>> posts=client.query('select * from (traverse in('posted_by') from (select * from person where @rid=#14:0) ) where @class='Post')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    posts=client.query('select * from (traverse in('posted_by') from (select * from person where @rid=#14:0) ) where @class='Post')
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> posts=client.query("select * from (traverse in('posted_by') from (select * from person where @rid=#14:0) ) where @class='Post'")
>>> for post in posts:
...     print post.content
... 
[ANOTHER GOOD RESULT]
>>> comments=client.query("select * from (traverse in('written_on') from (select * from (traverse in('posted_by') from (select * from person where @rid=#14:0) ) ) where @class='Comment'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyorient/orient.py", line 212, in query
    .prepare(( QUERY_SYNC, ) + args).send().fetch_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyorient/utils.py", line 47, in wrap_function
    return wrap(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyorient/utils.py", line 60, in wrap_function
    return wrap(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyorient/messages/commands.py", line 131, in prepare
    return super( CommandMessage, self ).prepare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 72, in prepare
    self._encode_field( x ) for x in self._fields_definition
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 72, in <genexpr>
    self._encode_field( x ) for x in self._fields_definition
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 200, in _encode_field
    buf = v.encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 65: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

although the last query runs on the OrientDB Studio and retrieve right result, but when trying to do this in python this error happens.

> **Note:** the data stored in the database is written in Arabic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an old version, at least before Oct 18, 2014. This bug should be fixed in latest versions.

[Commit SHA of Bug Fix](https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/commit/20ef3e817d00d502d5748c62c2cfd8e2fcaa24d4)

Comment: I tried to clone it and install manually but the same error happens
`Exception Value: 
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyorient-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/pyorient/messages/base.py in _encode_field, line 203`
this is the exceptions I had in the django debug mode.

Comment: I get the same error only if i specify unicode string type:
`u"select * from (traverse in('written_on') from (select * from (traverse in('posted_by') from (select * from person where @rid=#14:0) ) ) where @class='Comment'"`

Comment: you're right.
solved :)
but another issue would be :
what if I tried to query Arabic string?

Comment: Should works. There are some tests here: 
[test_utf8_string.py](https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/blob/master/test/test_utf8_string.py#L49)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your code (usually underneath the shebang statement), like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I ran into some issues with Unicode and Python2 myself. I rewrote my code to Python3, which handles Unicode text 'out of the box'

Comment: actually I already did, and the same problem.
this code is supposed to be a part of django app (views.py) and I wrote this line before all imports.
but if I return an HTTPResponse() with Arabic message no problems happen.